# Copy Cell To Another Sheet, one after another

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to find the solution to this for a while now and I do not believe I am searching for the right thing.

Basically what I want to do is copy a cell contents and paste it to another sheet and then delete the contents of the cell that was copied from.

I have one button that corresponds to each cell and I want to write a bit of code which enables you to do this at the click of a button.

Another issue is I don't know the code that would not constantly paste in the same cell over and over, but rather go to the next row and paste there.

What I have at the moment is the following:

```
Sub Macro1()


Range("I2").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Completed Tasks").Select
Range("A72").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Projects Live!").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
Range("H2").Select

End Sub
```

This only refers to the top cell and i have recorded a macro to show essentially what i want.

Hope you can help or point me in the right direction.

Comment: Two links to get you started. `1` Please avoid the use of `.Select/.Activate` [INTERESTING READ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)
`2` Find The [Last Row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub luxation()
    Range("I2").Copy Sheets("Completed Tasks").Range("A72")
    Range("I2").Clear
End Sub
```

This is for a single cell...............you would embed this kind of syntax in a loop.